# How to add SNI client hello extension using Schannel API?

Tags: ssl, sni, schannel

I'm trying to add SNI to my client-side program (C/C++) that uses Microsoft SDK's Schannel API for TLS.

I've searched everywhere but could not find any documentation on how Schannel supports SNI extension.
I looked up the documentation for  `AcquireCredentialsHandle()`, `InitializeSecurityContext()` but no success.

So, could anyone please help me with some example code?

Comment: On client side AFAIK there are no special requirements for using SNI. You just need a SNI capable Windows/SChannel version.

Answer (score 0):

The [SNI](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3546.txt) is specified as [part of the ClientHello](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2013/08/03/ssl-handshake-and-https-bindings-on-iis.aspx), which is generated by [`InitializeSecurityContext()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375924). Specficially, Schannel uses the 3rd parameter of that function for certificate validation, as well, as SNI; but not all versions of Windows support TLS extensions (which includes SNI).

TLS Extensions were first introduced in [Internet Explorer 7 beta 3 on Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/10/22/483795.aspx). Plus, even if your operating system supports it, TLS will likely be [turned off, by default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/08/aes-is-not-a-valid-cipher-for-sslv3.aspx).

There is a [working example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL) that shows SNI from the client and server side.